# Socket.io failing to log chat message in console

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm walking through the Socket.io [tutorial on creating a chat room](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/), and I'm having trouble getting my app to log the chat message to the console.

The app is logging when a user connects & disconnects, but it is not logging when a message is passed through.

Any thoughts?

The relevant parts of my index.html page:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function() {
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
</script>

<body>
  <ul id="messages"><ul>

  <form action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

My index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    console.log("message: " + msg);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten it to work!

Steps to solution:
- separate the script tag with the event listener into a separate JS file
- include that JS file in the same place the script tag was originally
- load the chatListener when the document is ready

My files now look like this and everything works beautifully:

**index.html:**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script src="main.js"></script>

<body>
  <ul id="messages"><ul>

  <form action="">
    <input class="chat" id="m" autocomplete="off" />
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
</body>
```

**index.js:** nothing changed

**main.js:**

```
var socket = io();

var chatListener = function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  chatListener();
})
```

In the end, I think it was a beginner's JS mistake; I was loading the script at the top of the page (as the tutorial suggested), and the event listener on the form was never registering.